# How to calculate Virtual Memory Size in Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, virtual-memory

[image]

I would like to know if there is a command/API call (or set of commands/API calls) that calculates each of (Virtual Memory, File Cache and App Memory) parameters listed in the screen shot above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vm_stat` and `sysctl` terminal commands. Although there was no straightforward way or documentation on how to extract the new attributes from these commands, we had to do some trial and error till we discovered the relations between parameters in the commands and the attribute we need to calculate.

The Steps are as the following:

1. Run `vm_stat`
2. Run "sysctl hw.memsize" and "sysctl vm.swapusage".
3. The relationship between Memory usage which appears in Activity Monitor and previous commands are described in [How to calc Memory usage in Mavericks programmatically](http://www.badrit.com/blog/2014/5/1/how-to-calc-memory-usage-in-mavericks-programmatically).

Sample output from `vm_stat`:

```
Mach Virtual Memory Statistics: (page size of 4096 bytes)
Pages free:                               24428.
Pages active:                           1039653.
Pages inactive:                          626002.
Pages speculative:                       184530.
Pages throttled:                              0.
Pages wired down:                        156244.
Pages purgeable:                           9429.
"Translation faults":                  14335334.
Pages copy-on-write:                     557301.
Pages zero filled:                      5682527.
Pages reactivated:                           74.
Pages purged:                             52633.
File-backed pages:                       660167.
Anonymous pages:                        1190018.
Pages stored in compressor:                 644.
Pages occupied by compressor:               603.
Decompressions:                              18.
Compressions:                               859.
Pageins:                                 253589.
Pageouts:                                     0.
Swapins:                                      0.
Swapouts:                                     0.
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here, because links on the Internet inevitably rot. All answers should be self-contained and stand alone, no matter what happens to the external resources. So it would be best if you [edit]ed your answer to *summarize* the solution described in the blog post.